# iTextSharp - Error with XMLWorkerHelper GetInstance using MemoryStream for PDFs

Tags: vb.net, itext, byte

I have a placeholder on the web page that I need to convert into a pdf(bytes).  My code was working but now for some reason it is giving me an error.

Previously, the code had the following line:

"Using writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)" however that produced an ERROR of DataStream is closed" so i changed the code as you see below.  The new ERROR is Object is not referenced.

Any help would be appreciated.

Error at:
iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss)

Error Msg: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
Protected Sub createPDF()

    Dim stringWriter As New StringWriter()
    Dim htmlTextWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)
    PlaceHolder1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter)

    'Create a byte array that will eventually hold our final PDF
    Dim bytes As [Byte]()

     Using ms = New MemoryStream()

      'Create an iTextSharp Document which is an abstraction of a PDF but **NOT** a PDF
      Using doc = New Document()

       'Using writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)
        Dim writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter
        writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)

            'Open the document for writing
            doc.Open()

            Dim example_html = htmlTextWriter.InnerWriter.ToString()
            Dim example_css = ".headline{font-size:200%}"

            Using msCss = New MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css))
                Using msHtml = New MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html))
                    'Error occurs here, next line
                    iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss)
                End Using
            doc.Close()
         End Using
    End Using

    bytes = ms.ToArray()
    'store into variable
    DocuSign.DocusignContracts.m_AddendumByte = ms.ToArray()
    DocuSign.DocusignContracts.m_AddendumLen = ms.ToArray().Length

    ms.Close()
End Using
```

End Sub

Comment: Inspect the contents of `example_html`

Comment: Thank you Chris, there was a div without its closing div tag.